# How to differentiate between the event being emitted - react-native (rn-tourguide)

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native, eventemitter

I am using a react-native package called as `rn-tourguide` which helps me in as the name suggest a tour guide for first time logged in users.

The working of `rn-tourguide` is to first wrap a `TourGuideProvider` around your main `App.js` and for using the functionalty you have to wrap `TourGuideZone` around you desired component's View.

**App.js**

```
<TourGuideProvider
   preventOutsideInteraction={true}
     {...{
       borderRadius: 16,
       tooltipComponent: TooltipComponent,
      }}>
   <NavStack notif={notifBool} />
</TourGuideProvider>
```

**TooltipComponent**

```
const TooltipComponent = ({
 isFirstStep,
 isLastStep,
 handleNext,
 handlePrev,
 handleStop,
 currentStep,
}) => (
(
  <View>
    <Text>{'Welcome'}</Text>
    <View>
      <TouchableOpacity>
        <Text>{'skip'}</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
      {!isFirstStep && (
        <TouchableOpacity
          onPress={() => handlePrev()}>
          <Text>{'prev'}</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      )}
      {!isLastStep && (
        <TouchableOpacity
          onPress={() => handleNext()}>
          <Text>{'next'}</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      )}
      {isLastStep && (
        <TouchableOpacity
          onPress={() => handleStop()}>
          <Text>{'finish'}</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      )}
    </View>
  </View>
 )
);
```

The problem i am facing is that when i am using the custom Component i.e. `TooltipComponent` , the functions passed handlePrev, handleNext, handleStop does not have a callback method.so if i am using the `TourGuideZone` in some another component i will have to listen to a event emitted by the package and check if its a 'start' or 'stop' and accordingly you can do you further process.

Because the event emitter is being run in `useEffect` all the emitters starts running before even they are called. these causes the start and stop event running simultaneously. also there is no keys (as per my understanding) provided to differentiate between the events that are emitted.

Is there anyway to differentiate between eventEmitter.on('start') and eventEmitter.on('stop').

**Demo.js**

```
const Demo = ({navigation}) => {
 const {
   canStart, // a boolean indicate if you can start tour guide
   start, // a function to start the tourguide
   stop, // a function  to stopping it
   eventEmitter, // an object for listening some events
   getCurrentStep,
   tourKey,
 } = useTourGuideController();

   useEffect(() => {
     if (canStart) {
       start();
     }
     return () => {
      stop();
    };
  }, [canStart]);

  const handleOnStop = () => {
    console.log('do something after stop');
  } 


   useEffect(() => {
     eventEmitter.on('start', ()=> console.log('do something'));
     eventEmitter.on('stop', handleOnStop);
       return () => {
     eventEmitter.on('start', ()=> console.log('do something'));
     eventEmitter.off('stop', handleOnStop);
    };
   }, [eventEmitter]);

   return(
     <View>
        <TourGuideZone
          tourKey={tourKey}
          zone={1}
          text={' hello'}
        />
     </View>
 )
}
```

Can anyone please help me on this , if i have mistakenly forgot to add something to make this work. thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi, I am also facing the same issue, have you been able to resolve the issue?

Comment: no, i have also raised an issue ..till now no response . i am trying another package called as react native copilot for now